# How can I create a Windows 7 user profile without the user logging in?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I've created a new user in Windows 7.

I now want to FTP into the PC as that user but it fails because the user profile does not yet exist under c:\users\

If I log in as that user first, it creates the profile and then I can FTP in fine.

Is there a way to create the data under c:\users\ without having to log in first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about what you are using for an FTP server, it is hard to be more precise, but it has to do with your FTP settings making the default directory something like %userprofile%.

Set the default login directory in the FTP server's settings to a static directory like: C:\ftp or C:\inetpub\ftp. As long as the user exists, and the permissions exist, you won't have any problems.

Comment: I also found that just adding the user to a group worked if the group had access to the default FTP directory.